# missing packages error in wine installation

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

i'm trying to install wine the latest version using the following command

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

but i faced some missing packages issues, so i tried to fix it through the command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends --fix-missing winehq-stable
```

even with that still unable to get the missed packages and i keep getting this error:

```
    Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/wine-stable-amd64_6.0.1~focal-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.winehq.org'
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/wine-stable_6.0.1~focal-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.winehq.org'
E: Aborting install.
```

how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: **Temporary** failure resolving 'dl.winehq.org'

Comment: so the problem from the packages host servers ?

Comment: I don't know but it's what the error message says. Try again later.

Comment: did you add a ppa as part of your attempt to install wine? That's a pretty important detail to omit. Also provide your ubuntu version.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah i think i added all the necessary PPAs i've been told to add, yet i keep running into this issue. i use the latest ubuntu release 20.04 LTS

Comment: ppas are usually part of the problem, not the solution, when installing wine. Do you have a specific need for a version of wine so advanced that you can't just install the version from the Ubuntu repositories? Otherwise I suggest using ppa-purge to remove any wine-related ppas you installed, and install `wine-stable` from the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so guys I've been fighting with this problem for quite a time and finally found the solution.
the wine repository uses https protocol to transport its packages so i had to install `https` package on my maching using the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

then i retyped the command :

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

or
`sudo apt install --install-recommends --fix-missing winehq-stable` to just get the missed packages.

then the problem solved.